# send response from nodejs express to angular app

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, express

I am calling an api of sending OTP from my nodejs app. I need to send the response of that OTP Api to the angular app.

my api service on angular look like this:

```
sendOtp(params): Observable<any> {
    return this.apiService.post("/user/send-otp", params)
}
```

my router on express app look like this

```
this.router.post("/user/send-otp", userController.sendOtpMessage);
```

and the code inside userController look like this.

```
static sendOtpMessage(req, res ,next) {

    const phone = req.body.phone;

    var http = require("https");

    var options = {
      "method": "GET",
      "hostname": "api.msg91.com",
      "port": null,
      "path": `/api/v5/otp?mobile=${phone}`,
      "headers": {
        "content-type": "application/json"
      }
    };

    var callOtpApi = http.request(options, function (res) {
      var chunks = [];

      res.on("data", function (chunk) {
        chunks.push(chunk);
      });

      res.on("end", function () {
        var body = Buffer.concat(chunks);
        console.log(body.toString());
        // I need to send this data in response to my angular app ==>> body.toString()
      });

    });
    callOtpApi.write();
    callOtpApi.end();
  }
```

OTP Api ref document: https://docs.msg91.com/p/tf9GTextN/e/B1NUt3C8MY/MSG91

Comment: What is your question? Note that you are overriding the Express `res` variable within your callback. Rename one of them. Then you can look into piping the response from your api call into the res for express.

Comment: thanks, overriding was the issue i was facing while sending the response back to the angular app. My question how do I send response to angular app.

Comment: i think you can't send response if you have a callback approach for HTTP request, you might want to look for promise based approach @ds97

Comment: @ds97 In order to send the data back to the angular client, you need to call the `.send()` methog (see [docu](http://expressjs.com/en/5x/api.html#res.send)). This method can be called on the `res` parameter from the `sendOtpMessage` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the code above is missing the `res.send()` to return the data from server. Could you please try with this?

```
static sendOtpMessage(req, res ,next) {
  const serverRes = res;

  // Rest of your code
  ...
  var callOtpApi = http.request(options, function (res) {
    // Rest of your code
    ...

    res.on("end", function () {
      var body = Buffer.concat(chunks);
      console.log(body.toString());
      // Return data to client          
      serverRes.send(body.toString());
    });

    // Rest of your code
    ...
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call the msg91 api using   **axios**

```
const axios = require('axios');

async function  sendOtpTOUser(phone) {
 const  template =  "template _id";
 const  apiKey = "api_key";         
 const sendotp = "https://api.msg91.com/api/v5/otp?template_id="+template+"&mobile="+phone+"&authkey="+apiKey;
                 let request_options1 = {
                  method: 'get',
                  url: sendotp
              };  
     
  let otpResponse = await axios(request_options1);
  console.log(otpResponse.data)  
  return otpResponse.data;              
}
```

it will return the object as

```
{ request_id: '3166686e7867313634383535', type: 'success' }
```